# python tcp/ip socket datastream gets interupted

Tags: python, sockets

I use a tcp/ip to rs232 converter from expert EX-9132 where i connect to a datalogger to receive data, after sending a request (chr27 via tcp) for requesting data, the transmission is interupted before receiving all the available data. I like to finish the transmission after all data has been received. The below code is the python code.

Does anyone have an idea how to extend the receive time?

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = '192.168.1.5'
PORT = 4660
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send( b'\x1b' ) #this is "chr27" to sent to the device

data = ""
data += s.recv(200)
f = open('/home/fspr/minicom/201104cc-tcp.txt', 'a')
data1 = data.replace("/t", ";")
f.write(data1)
f.close()
print data.replace("/t", ";")
s.close()
```

Comment: For your next question, please remember to put your code into a code block. You can do that by highlighting all your code and pressing the button that has a pair of curly brackets, {}. It really increases readability a lot. I have added an edit request, but it's generally better if you were to do it when you first create the question.

Comment: does the device on the other side always terminate it's data string with a unique character sequence?

Answer (score 3):

Your code only calls recv(200) once.  The way recv() works is it will return at least 1 byte and at most 200 (in this case) bytes.  It will block if there is no data available.  It will return an empty string when the server closes the connection.

Without knowing the full protocol, I can only guess, but you at least need to loop over the recv() call until you have the full data sent from the server.  If, for example, the server sends a bunch of data and then closes the connection, something like this would work:

```
data = ""
while True:
    chunk = s.recv(200)
    if not chunk: break
    data += chunk
```

Since this is a datalogger, another guess I have is that you will receive lines of data until you tell the server to stop (maybe by sending another character).  In this case:

```
data = ""
while True:
    chunk = s.recv(200)
    if not chunk: break
    data += chunk

    # Test for a complete line in the data buffer.
    n = data.find('\n')
    if n != -1:
        # Remove the line from the front of the buffer.
        # Leave any remaining lines or partial lines in data.
        line,data = data[:n+1],data[n+1:]
        print line
```

Note that the way TCP works, the server could send() two separate lines data, but recv() could recieve in one call a partial line, or a complete line plus a partial line, so you have to buffer the data and extract only complete lines from the buffer.

Hope this helps...

Comment: HI Mark, you hit the nail on the head it works perfectly. I have increased the s.recv(1024) and all the data arrived. Thx a lot for your reply and your quick reply!. One question is: while True: sets a flag while receiving data right? Then the in not chunk looks to see if the flag is set to 0 then the data += chunk adds the pieces together????

Comment: Mike, thx for your question. I think there is a EOF but I'm not sure!!

Comment: @fspr02, `while True:` is an infinite loop.  It will exit if `s.recv` returns an empty string, indicating the server closed the connection.  Also remember what I said about recv...It is perfectly valid for a server to send, say, 2048 bytes of data, but require two or more recv calls to receive the data.  A TCP connection is just a stream of bytes, and it is up to the programmer to follow a protocol to determine when all the data has been received.  Your program may work now with a single recv(), but may break under a heavily loaded network where TCP breaks the message into multiple packets.

Comment: thx Mark, it takes 80 seconds to arrive which seems to me a little long. (the file is 280 line each 26 characters long)